# При подключении новой видеокарты не идет загрузка

Tags: железо, видеокарта

Решил подцепить новую видеокарту GIGABYTE GV-N630-2GI на материнку GIGABYTE GA-H61M-S2PV. Загружается экран с логотипом материнки и зависает, кулера крутятся идет один короткий писк, однако ни в биос, ни в безопасный режим не пускает на нажатия кавиш не реагирует. После 30 секунд экран гаснет(однако кулера крутятся).
Подскажите совместимость данных устройств и в чем может быть проблема? Биос сбрасывал - реакции 0.
Пока мое предположение не хватает мощности БП - 230Вт.

Comment: `Рекомендуемый блок питания 350 Вт` и `1 короткий писк - Ошибок не обнаружено, ПК исправен`

Comment: Потому и написал, что писк - все норм. 
Про рекомендуемый блок - да знаю. Ответьте про совместимость этих 2-х устройств.